# How to address N+1 problem in django with prefetch related?

Tags: python, django, query-optimization

With the following code I am getting N numbers of queries based on the loop. How to avoid that ?

I tried using prefetch_related but that didn't worked or am i doing the wrong way ?

models

```
class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  ....

class ProdcutOffer(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="offers")
  ....

def my_view(request):
  qs = Product.objects.filter(is_active=True).prefetch_related("offers")
  data = []
  for product in qs:
     data.append(
            {
             ....,
             "offer":product.offers.filter(is_active=True, is_archived=False).last()
            }
          )

    paginator = Paginator(data, 10)
    try:
        page_obj = paginator.page(page_num)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page_obj = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page_obj = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return page_obj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using django's `Prefetch` method inside the `prefetch_rleated`. You can pass a custom queryset inside the Prefetch method.

You could do something like this:

```
qs = Product.objects.filter(is_active=True).prefetch_related(
  models.Prefetch(
    "offers",
     queryset=ProductOffer.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_archived=False),
     to_attr="product_offers"
  )
)
data = []
for product in qs:
   try:
      data.append({"offers": product.product_offers[0]})
   except IndexError:
      pass
```

the to_attr attribute will simply create a new attribute for the queryset which is a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

We can first introduce a [**`FilteredRelation`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects) that contains the primary key of the latest `ProductOffer`, and then select related these:

```
from django.db.models import FilteredRelation, OuterRef, Q, Subquery

qs = Product.objects.annotate(
    latest_offer=FilteredRelation(
        'offer',
        condition=Q(
            post=Subquery(
                ProductOffer.objects.filter(
                    is_active=True, is_archived=False, product_id=OuterRef('pk')
                )
                .order_by('-pk')
                .values('pk')[:1]
            )
        ),
    )
).select_related('latest_offer')
```

the `Product`s that arise from this will have an extra attribute `.latest_offer` that contains the latest offer. You thus can use this to render it for example as:

```
{% for product in page_obj %}
    {{ product }}: {{ product.latest_offer }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i have one confusion, isn't `prefetch_related` supposed to reduce that in the first place only ?

Comment: @D_P: what do you mean with *in the first place only*?

Comment: I have used prefetch_related inside this query `Product.objects.filter(is_active=True).prefetch_related("offers")` shouldn't it fetch the related offers of the product in a single query since it is executing separate query for each product ?

Comment: i think  it is executing each query since there is a filter `product.offers.filter(is_active=True, is_archived=False).last()`  if it was like this `product.offers.all()` it will not execute another query

Comment: @D_P: no, this will be done as an `SubQuery`, so actually *inside* the first (and only) query. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: The simple proof is that Django does not really "understand" what `OuterRef` means as in Django never build a parallel query system in Python: the queries are compiled in SQL, and Django thus can not translate `.filter(pk__in=[1,4])` for example in filtering at the Python side. So the `OuterRef` somehow *has* to be compiled to SQL.